# which specification must consider for implementing WCF security over internet

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I want to know  some main specification must be considered when i want to implement WCFsecruity over internet.what is main specification  that i should consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specification to be followed a rule. In general you should consider following good security practices that are used in every HTTP server/client application and exist in the form of **security guidelines**.

I suppose a good point to start would be [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648318.aspx) giving an intro to security fundamentals for web services.  I would also suggest the [Improving Web Services Security ebook](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/) which provides with very useful guidelines.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks for your answering,Do you have a best practice article for this title??

Comment: Added a reference on my edited answer. You should upvote the specific answer. It is very important for other users navigating to your question to be able to identify useful answers quickly.